# How to use field.set() in create function for Django REST Framework ModelSerializer?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have an intermediate model called `RoomMarket` connecting 2 related models. `Market` - `RoomMarket` - `Room`. When I tried to insert a record for `RoomMarket` using writable nested serializer I got an error:

> TypeError at /room_markets/
>   Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use regions.set() instead.

Here's my simplified `models.py`:

```
class RecordStatus:
    published = 'Published'
    drafted = 'Drafted'
    hidden = 'Hidden'
    status = [
        (published, 'Published'),
        (drafted, 'Drafted'),
        (hidden, 'Hidden'),
    ]


class Market(models.Model, RecordStatus):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    regions = models.ManyToManyField(Region)
    languages = models.ManyToManyField(Language)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=RecordStatus.status, default=RecordStatus.published)

    @property
    def get_product_variations(self):
        return Product.objects.filter(distributor__region__market=self).distinct().count()


class Room(models.Model, RecordStatus):
    style = models.ForeignKey(Style, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    markets = models.ManyToManyField(Market, through='RoomMarket')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='room_images', width_field=None, height_field=None,
                              max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=RecordStatus.status, default=RecordStatus.published)


class RoomMarket(models.Model):
    market = models.ForeignKey(Market, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    landing_page = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.market, self.room)
```

Here's my `serializers.py`:

```
class CustomRelatedField(serializers.RelatedField):
    def display_value(self, instance):
        return instance

    def to_representation(self, value):
        return str(value)

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        model = self.queryset.model
        return model.objects.get(id=data)


class MarketSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    regions = CustomRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Region.objects.all())
    languages = CustomRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Language.objects.all())
    variation = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='get_product_variations')
    landing_page = serializers.SerializerMethodField(source='get_landing_page')

    class Meta:
        model = Market
        fields = ['id', 'regions', 'languages', 'name', 'status', 'variation', 'landing_page']
        depth = 1

    @staticmethod
    def get_landing_page(market):
        queryset = RoomMarket.objects.filter(market=market)
        if queryset.exists():
            for r in queryset:
                return r.room.id
        else:
            return '-'


class RoomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    style = CustomRelatedField(many=False, queryset=Style.objects.all())
    markets = CustomRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Market.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Room
        fields = ['id', 'markets', 'style', 'image', 'name', 'status']


class RoomMarketSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    market = MarketSerializer()
    room = CustomRelatedField(many=False, queryset=Room.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = RoomMarket
        fields = ['id', 'market', 'room', 'landing_page']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # create market data for Market model.
        market_data = validated_data.pop('market')
        market = Market.objects.create(**market_data)

        # create RoomMarket and set market FK.
        room_market = RoomMarket.objects.create(market=market, **validated_data)

        # return RoomMarket instance.
        return room_market
```

Here's my `views.py`:

```
class RoomMarketView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [permissions.DjangoModelPermissions]
    queryset = RoomMarket.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RoomMarketSerializer
```

The JSON format I use to POST data:

```
{
    "market": {
        "regions": [1,2],
        "languages": [1,2],
        "name": "Asia",
        "status": "Published"
    },
    "room": 2,
    "landing_page": true
}
```

I've read several SO questions regarding this matter but most cases are on Form/View not `create` function in `ModelSerializer` class. What should I change in the `create` function of my intermediate model `ModelSerializer` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you creating `market` instance you pass `region` and `language` object to `create()` method. You should pass it to `set()` instead:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    # create market data for Market model.
    market_data = validated_data.pop('market')
    regions = market_data.pop("regions")
    languages = market_data.pop("languages")
    market = Market.objects.create(**market_data)
    market.regions.set(regions)
    market.languages.set(languages)
```

Comment: Thank you @neverwalkaloner for explaining it to me. Can I apply this to `update` function too? Because I'm sure I also need to explicitly define the `update` function.

Comment: @Nathan welcome! Sure you can use it in update. But note that `set()` replace the set of related objects. If you don't need it, you probably better to use `add()` in `update()`. Check related part of doc for more details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add